# Gsoap error 28 : SOAP_TCP_ERROR

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, gsoap

I am using gsoap for Symbian S60 3rd Edition FP2 in a Qt application. I am making several requests to a WS every 5 seconds. After 2 hours the application stops being able to connect to the WS and I get this Error 28: SOAP_TCP_ERROR from gsoap. If I stop the application and start it again it is able to connect to the WS again. Why is this happening?

I've put the gsoap WS call in a for loop and it stops connecting to the WS at the 892th time, every time I run it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do several things as a prework:

- enable DBGLOG at gsoap
- use soap_faultdetail at client side.

I'm 99% sure that it will give you a tcp connection timeout error which means that connection handshake has just failed.
If it is so, it means that WS has not accepted the connection for some reason. The source of problems might lay somewhere between proxy/firewall/os/buggy ws/driver to name just few of them. Because of that, one can use reconnection attempt. I'm not familiar with symbian, but in the windows OS reconnection is performed behind the scenes:

- see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938209.aspx

By default, reconnection attempt is made twice but this behaviour could be changed either by registry parameter, driver or winsock.

I think you have to write explicit connection-retry subroutine at your application level and force gSOAP to use it (see hooks section at gSOAP documentations) or just call soap_connect couple of times if it returns error.

NOTE: introduction of connection_timeout at gsoap level may be confusing.
If you will decide to put this one (if you do not already have this) in your code, perform some tests wether the reconnection attempt is really perfomed within this timeout or not. 
What I'm just trying to say is that your application could set timeout to 30 minutes, but your OS will put SYN packet into the WS host just couple of times within let's say couple of first seconds. If the WS host will not respond with SYN-ACK for some reason, your gsoap's tcp_connect subroutine will fall into 30minutes waste-of-time-loop.